# Field Collection values in json data document view

Tags: views, entities, 8

I am wondering if I am hitting the limits of what can be done with the json data document view for displaying output and whether I need to just write my own module or use php's json_encode to do this.

Essentially I have a content type called 'projects' and I have created several views that output json data so that I can use them within the angularjs frontend I am embedding into my Drupal 7 site.

On 'projects' there is a field collections field for 'team'. This consists of a node reference to a 'person' and a text-field for 'role'.

I can use a relationship in my view to access the field-collection items but I am currently stuck as the field delta (which I have set to 'all', since I want to see all associated team members for a project'). This is causing the json view to duplicate each project many times over when there are multiple team members, and also I am not able to get the node reference for the team member.

Is this something that is possible to do with views/json? Or should I just hack up my own json from within the page template or a module using PHP?

Thanks
- J

Comment: `hook_preprocess_views_views_json_style_simple()` may be of use here, but sometimes writing your own callback is the way to go. Example usage: http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupalgap/tree/drupalgap.module#n278